# Ansible: check supplied tags are valid before running a playbook

Tags: logging, ansible

I suspect that this is trying to be too clever (and failing), but - 
especially in development of a PB, it's really useful to use tags to limit the roles which are run - so for example we have: (snippet of the playbook)
...

```
 - { role: yum,      tags: [ 'yum' ] }
 - { role: proxy,    tags: [ 'proxy' ]  }
 - { role: firewall, tags: [ 'firewall' ] }
```

Now occasionally, I run with a misspelled tag - eg

```
$ ansible-playbook servername, user=fred  my_playbook --tags=firewal
```

And pre-tasks get run, as do post tasks, which makes it appear that something is happening, but of course, no task matches the incorrectly-entered tag.  I do pick this up in logging ( every role does this:

```
- include_tasks: includes/log_role_completion.yml this_role={{ role_name }}
```

which resolves to this:

```
- name: "Setup completed_roles list"
  set_fact:
    completed_roles: "{{ this_role }}"
  changed_when: false
  when: completed_roles is not defined

- name: "Add role to list of completed roles"
  set_fact:
    completed_roles: "{{ completed_roles }} {{ this_role }}"
  changed_when: false
  when: completed_roles != this_role
```

Then, a post_tasks role writes the list of completed roles - or a message saying that none were run possibly because of a misspelt tag.  This works nicely - and I know that ansible writes logs, but they are either verbose, or cryptic, and I like to have /var/log/ansible on the target with something like this:

```
Ansible version 2.6.2 run commenced at 2018-08-31: 20:23:40 GMT using account vmw-user
Ansible version 2.6.2 run completed at 2018-08-31: 20:23:40 GMT for roles chrony, proxy, and log_complete
```

That's really useful, BUT (and here's the question,finally) I'd rather have the playbook check if a tag is supplied which doesn't match any tag used in the playbook, and stop - thus warning me that I've misspelt something.  this would also prevent a playbook from being incompletely run - the role with the misspelled tag would not run at all, which could cause a problem.

The variable vars.ansible_run_tags contains the user-supplied tags: is there some way of seeing which tags are set in a playbook?  I don't want to run in check-mode first, and manually parse the output - I'd like it to be automatic.

Comment: Feel free to edit out the cruft about logging to /var/log/ansible - I put it there in case someone finds it useful or says "you can do this better like so ..."

Comment: BTW I am aware that I could always add tags for common misspellings - eg firewal as in the example above, but that's ugly and incomplete.

Comment: I use tags everywhere and a typo can take so long to spot. The only thought I had was a bash wrapper for `ansible-playbook` that pulled out the tags lists passed in to `--tags` or `--skip-tags` and then verified they appeared in the list reported by `--list-tags`, only if all are present would it make the real call. But I'm busy and I bet that will come back to bite me. I just feel there should be a `--strict` option that does this kind of check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO there is no such variable to "see which tags are set in a playbook". There are only *ansible_run_tags* and *ansible_skip_tags*. I'm afraid the only option would be to write an ansible-playbook wrapper to check if the supplied tags are present in the playbook ("to run in check-mode first, and manually parse the output").

BTW. Below is a simplified list of completed roles

```
completed_roles: "{{ completed_roles|default('') }} {{ this_role }}"
```

To avoid "pre-tasks get run, as do post tasks, which makes it appear that something is happening" you might want to use *import_roles* and *when* condition instead of tags. Below is an example where role3.yml and role4.yml print a message only.

**play.yml**

```
- hosts:
    - localhost
  tasks:
    - import_role: name=role3
      when: selector|default('') in [ 'role3', 'all_roles' ]
    - import_role: name=role4
      when: selector|default('') in [ 'role4', 'all_roles' ]
```

.

```
> ansible-playbook -e selector=role4 play.yml | grep msg
    "msg": "role4"
```

.

```
> ansible-playbook -e selector=all_roles play.yml | grep msg
    "msg": "role3"
    "msg": "role4"
```

Comment: Thanks - that confirms what I was thinking, and the default() filter is of course the right way to do things, and makes everything much more readable.  I'm logging the start of the run with the date and {{ansible_run_tags}} , and at the end, am logging completed roles, so that pretty much covers it.